# Which part/parts does entering the crisis modify?

Tags: post-modifier

> The strength of the recovery is projected to vary significantly across countries, depending on access to medical interventions, effectiveness of policy support, exposure to cross-country spillovers, and structural characteristics **entering the crisis**.

Source: https://www.imf.org/en/Publications/WEO/Issues/2021/01/26/2021-world-economic-outlook-update

Does the part "entering the crisis" only modifies "structural characteristics", or it also modifies the other three parts, namely, access to medical interventions, effectiveness of policy support, exposure to cross-country spillovers?

Comment: It seems to be the participial construction. That means "beginning the crisis".

Comment: It isn't modifying anything.  Paraphrasing that last phrase: "structural characteristics that already existed at the start of the crisis."

Comment: @BillJ But structural characteristics can not enter the crisis themselves, right? The subject for the clause should be countries, i.e. the structural characteristics of (these countries) when (these countries) enter the crisis?

Comment: I think you're probably right. In which case the whole expression "depending on access to medical interventions, effectiveness of policy support, exposure to cross-country spillovers, and structural characteristics" is a supplement (a kind of parenthetical). A comma after "characteristics" would have helped.

Comment: @Then I'am confused why "when" can be omited here if this part is used to modify all the four parts instead of only modifying " structural characteristics". We usually omit that/which and when(where the antecedent also refers to a time) if they are used in an attributive caluse . Therefore, I want to know the grammar that says "when" can be omitted in this kind of situation.

Comment: No one is saying that it modifies all four parts, but that it modifies only "countries". As I said the intervening expression is a supplement, i..e. not integrated into the clause. Consider "countries entering the crisis", where "entering the crisis" is a gerund-participial clause modifying "countries". It's semantically similar to the relative construction "countries that are entering the crisis".

Comment: I don't see that a temporal meaning is intended here, so forget "when" -- it's irrelevant. The noun phrase is "countries entering the crisis". I've already explained the grammar.

Comment: I can understand this part ——"entering the crisis" is a gerund-participial clause modifying "countries" and this part _  It's semantically similar to the relative construction "countries that are entering the crisis".   But for the original sentence, it's "structural characteristics" entering the crisis, not "countries" entering the crisis.